# Get different Classes in hashchange simple_html_dom.php

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I want to get specific div data from a website.When i run this link `http://website.com`

It give me all deals.When i run `http://website.com/#BEAUTY` It give me only those deals which is related to BEAUTY.

How i can get contents of `http://website.com/#BEAUTY` using

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://website.com/#BEAUTY', false, $context);
$html = str_get_html($homepage);//this code give me all deals now
```

The html classes are like this

```
class ="hub_categoryDeal Dubai  Healthcare BEAUTY HAIR_REMOVAL1 LASER_HAIR_REMOVAL Dubai"
```

Comment: Try using cUrl => http://stackoverflow.com/a/18721026/1519058

Comment: It doesn't work like that. #BEAUTY is just a named a element. The request is the same.

Comment: yes request is the same,so how we will differenciat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the website that you're looking it, it is difficult to know what the page code looks like, but assuming that you want all the elements with the class 'BEAUTY', you can use this query:

```
$html->find('.BEAUTY')
```